# Checking if JSONObject is null, and in doing so crashes my application

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to see if the `JSONObject` 'FirstItemMGNAME2' is null, however when it is null it just crashes the program, and when it is not null, it just displays the else statement.

In short, im just trying to see if a string exsits in a JSONObject, and create an if statement

```
JSONObject FirstItemMGNAME2 = FirstItemArrayMG.getJSONObject(FirstItemArrayMG.length() - 2);
if (FirstItemMGNAME2.isNull("name")){
    FirstItemIDMGNAME2 = "1";
}
else {
    FirstItemIDMGNAME2 = FirstItemMGNAME2.getString("name");
}
```

Here is the logcat when the app crashes

```
08-21 16:14:40.237 20945-20945/com.kripzy.lolbuilds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kripzy.lolbuilds, PID: 20945
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
  at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:491)
  at com.kripzy.lolbuilds.Aatrox$JSONTask.onPostExecute(Aatrox.java:447)
  at com.kripzy.lolbuilds.Aatrox$JSONTask.onPostExecute(Aatrox.java:67)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
  at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

As people asked for all of my code here it - http://pastebin.com/JYsinqRw (had to be on pastebin due to the body being limtited to 30,000 characters)

Comment: You are still trying to access a null object hence, the NPE.

Comment: @Shaishav how do i fix this?

Comment: What was the logcat message for error?

Comment: @shawon here it is - http://pastebin.com/md4fsUeg

Comment: It's null pointer exception on List.size() . please provide your full code.

Comment: Your stacktrace exists inside an Adapter, which has nothing to do with the code you've posted

Comment: you are getting error in ArrayAdapter its difficult to trace error without your ArrayAdapter code. But i am confused how a string can be assign to a  JSONObject like FirstItemIDMGNAME2 = "1"; this statement

Answer (score 0):

Try `optJSONObjet(String arg1)`. It returns `null` if there is no field. `getJSONObject` will throw `JSONException` instead of returning `null`.

or

`FirstItemMGNAME2` may be `null`

Comment: well define little bit more about optJSONObject(String agr1)

Comment: JSONObject optJSONObject (String name)
Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONObject, or null otherwise. https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: but what about isNull(key) check and optString()

Comment: the field i told is a jsonobject's element. and above code, arguments are not null. they are"name". also I didnt test if an argument is null XD. anyway it seems that the questioner's problem is not from parsing jsonobject..

Answer (score 0):

Try comparing with Json String not with json object like

```
    if (FirstItemMGNAME2.getString("name").equals("")){
            FirstItemIDMGNAME2 = "1"   
            }
            else {
            FirstItemIDMGNAME2 = FirstItemMGNAME2.getString("name");
            }
```

if this does not fix plz send your json structure

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by just putting it inside a try catch block -

```
try {

JSONObject FirstItemMGNAME3 = FirstItemArrayMG.getJSONObject(FirstItemArrayMG.length() - 3);
                    if (FirstItemMGNAME3.isNull("name")){
                        FirstItemIDMGNAME3 = "1";
                    }
                    else {
                        FirstItemIDMGNAME3 = FirstItemMGNAME3.getString("name");
                    }
} catch (JSONException c) {
    c.printStackTrace();}
```